# Android: Tilting mobile makes ImageView content disappear / URI refreshed

Tags: android, uri, imageview, android-contentresolver

Thank you in advance for any responses. I am facing rather a trivial problem.
Hardware: Motorola (Android phone)

I am displaying an image in an imageview. The image itself is grabbed off a URI via ContentResolver. The problem is that whenever I tilt my mobile, the imageview gets blank. By tracing the log and variables I found out that the relevant URI goes back to its default (i.e. null) value whenever I tilt the mobile.

Of course there is a workaround for it i.e. using static variables. But I am wondering if there is another solution since I would really like to pass the URIs around in functions to do what I desire with my application.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity is restarted automatically whenever the orientation changes between portrait and landscape. Check out these [two](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) [articles](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) for ways to handle this.

Comment: Restarting the activity actually makes sense if you think about it. Many applications define different layouts, images and so on for different orientations. So the activity gets reloaded with different settings.

Comment: @socken23 We agree. I wasn't trying to imply that the restarting behaviour was bad, just pointing out articles that show how to make it less obvious.

Comment: Sorry, it was more of an addition to your comment so I didn't say you were implying. So we all agree ;-)

Comment: Thank you Ryanm and Socken23, I have been reading about this behaviour, let's see how the implementation of returning a template object goes with this. Regards.